# ReactJs : npm erorr with respect to node-sass

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, node-sass, npm-audit

While trying to `run npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` to fix few vulnerabilities in a sample react app, I came about this error which I am not able to find a fix for. Can I get some help with regards to this? I am new to reactjs and I am trying out a project.

I encountered this issue first when I installed firebase using npm. When I installed firebase I got few vulnerabilities warnings. Thats when I ran `run npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force`

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\Work\\React LEarn\\crwn-clothing\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.10.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\Jishnu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Jishnu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Work\\React LEarn\\crwn-clothing\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Work\React LEarn\crwn-clothing\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jishnu\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-10T13_07_03_839Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I had been facing the same issue just now.

Answer (score 0):

try this, i think it relates to incompatibility of node-sass version

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```